# ios 6 - issue in MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am creating Map app, i have display **MKAnnotationView** on MKMap, i have not done any subclass for that,

My viewForAnnotation delegate method is :

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }
    else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])
    {
        static NSString * const identifier = @"MyCustomAnnotation";

        MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (annotationView)
        {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        else
        {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                          reuseIdentifier:identifier];

        }
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin"];
        UIImageView *imgview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50,50)];
        imgview.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        imgview.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imgview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bus"];
        imgview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        UIView *lftView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50,50)];
        lftView.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [lftView addSubview:imgview];

        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView=lftView;
        annotationView.draggable = YES;
        annotationView.tag=101;
        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

And My outPut is Perfect in iOS 7 :

[image]

But in iOS 6 leftCalloutAccessoryView comes out of annotaionview, it display like:

[image]

So how can i Fix this issue in iOS 6.?

Comment: By the way (completely unrelated to your problem): You can optimize the code by moving the setting of the annotation view properties (from .canShowCallout upto .tag) to _inside_ the 2nd `else` part (after the `initWithAnnotation`) since these properties are the same for all annotations.  You don't need to set them if a view is being re-used.  Also, using `tag` with annotation views should be unnecessary (there are better ways to identify them).

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says about leftCalloutAccessoryView:

> The view to display on the left side of the standard callout bubble.
>   The default value of this property is nil. The left callout view is
>   typically used to display information about the annotation or to link
>   to custom information provided by your application. The height of your
>   view should be 32 pixels or less.

Seems to be that iOS7 callouts automatically adjust the size of accessory view, but iOS6 ones - not.

Try to change your hardcoded CGRects to 32px height.

Comment: if i set 32 hrdcoded, than in 7 it will not show proper. :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have solved your problem, but for the benefits of others looking for answer to similar issues...

In iOS 7, the size of the image in the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` is NOT automatically adjusted. The exact size is about 45x45. Your image of 50x50 is actually cropped-off at the bottom if you look carefully (reduce title & subtitle texts to less than 4 characters and you will see what I mean).

So, simply display the image in 45x45 size in iOS 7, 32x32 in iOS 6.

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)   ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0"))
    UIImageView *imgview=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
else
    UIImageView *imgview=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 45)];
```

(Assuming you are supporting iOS 6 and above.)